# How does application web url redirection work?

Tags: java, spring, redirect

I have an application in the production server that is build using spring. When I use the web url to access the application the application is redirected to another application after few seconds. How can one application redirect my application and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is change your client to disable following redirects. This may or may not be easily configurable (depends on how you're connecting to the remote HTTP server), but it should be possible.

HTTP clients make requests to an HTTP server – your application is a one such client making a request. The HTTP server can respond in many different ways, one of which is to send an [HTTP redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection). This is a way for the server to say: *you have asked for page X, but I have decided that you want page Y instead*. The behavior of a redirect is that the server responds back to the client "please see page Y", and the client then decides what to do. The server does this by sending a specific [response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) back to the client, along with the new url for Y. Right now, your client application is following redirects.

Note that this different from *forwarding* a request. In a redirect, the client *knows* that they asked for X but are being told to get Y instead. In a forward, the client asks for X and the server itself returns Y without notifying the client.

Comment: If page redirection is done using client id and client secret, do you see any hope of prevent it